# Get 500 - Internal server error When accidentally edited wwwroot file sharing

Tags: asp.net, file-sharing

I was trying to create virtual directive for `wwwroot`, but I got a config error. So I googled that and found out people talking about permission stuff.

I tried many ways and accidentally edited the file sharing property of `wwwroot` file. Now, I cannot even visit my site (Got `500 Internal server error` when browser the site) and modify any code inside the `wwwroot` file.

The wired thing is that in the security property, I can see my account have full control of the file. Could some one help me out? It is emergency!

Comment: PLease post the exact error ?

Comment: I guess you use IIS? Notice that IIS has a special account which needs the permissions, it has nothing to do with your account.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I changed back to previous permission, the 500 Internal server error was gone, but now it has another error. Compilation Error: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately. I created a new question here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30991951/server-error-in-application-asp-net